Migration of MassTransit managed classic mirrored RabbitMq queues to quorum ones
I have a lot of queues managed by MassTransit using RabbitMq as transport. These queues are currently classic mirrored queues and need to switch to quorum queues. Traffic disruption is not an option and I cannot afford to lose messages.
According to RabbitMq documentation, this migration cannot be made in place (ie it is not possible to change the type of an already queue created).
I know how to configure MassTransit so that new created queues are directly created with quorum as type (using IQueueConfigurator.SetQuorumQueue) but I don't know how to migrate already created durable queues.
Can MassTransit could help with this migration?

MassTransit will not help with your migration, you'll need to come up with an approach to migrate to a new broker instance with quorum queues.

@ChrisPatterson That's what I thought I understood from my search. Thanks for the confirmation.
